# Finding the mgf, expectation and variance of random sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: expected-value, variance, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

**Question**

Consider the random sum
$$Y = I(N>0)\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n$$

where $\left(X_n \right)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of independently and identically distributed random variables that is independent of the random variable $N$ which has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, and $I(N> 0)$ is the indicator function for the event $[N > 0]$. Assume each $X_n$ has MGF $M_X(t)$.

1. By using a suitable conditioning argument or otherwise, find $M_Y (t)$, the MGF of Y.
2. By finding appropriate derivatives of $M_Y(t)$, calculate the mean and variance of Y.

HINT: Recall that the chain rule states that if $u(x)=g(w(x))$, then $u'(x) = w'(x)g'(w(x))$.

3. Check your answers to Question 2 by calculating $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $Var[Y]$ using a simpler and more direct method.

**My attempt**

1.
$$\begin{aligned}
M_Y(t)& = \mathbb{E}(e^{tY})\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E} \left( e^{t \sum_{n=1}^N X_n} \vert N = j \right)\right]\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left( e^{t \sum_{n=1}^j X_n} \right)\right]\\
& = \mathbb{E} \left[ (M_X(t))^j \right]
\end{aligned}$$

Now I am stuck. Is my attempt for Question 1 is correct? If it is, how should I continue with Questions 2 and 3?

Any intuitive explanations will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the law of $N$ ? Is it poisson as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to write $N = j$ explicitly.  The law of total expectation is
$$M_Y(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tY}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{tY} \mid N]].$$  The innermost expectation is conditioned on $N$, so is a function of the random variable $N$.  We note
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tY} \mid N] = \mathbb{E}[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^N X_i} \mid N] = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^N e^{tX_i} \,\Biggl|\, N \Biggr. \right] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \prod_{i=1}^N M_X(t) = M_X(t)^N.$$
(It is worth mentioning at this step that if $N = 0$, then $M_X(t)^N = 1$ which is consistent with the definition of $Y$, so there is no further need for the indicator function.)
From here, we now must compute
$$\mathbb{E}[M_X(t)^N],$$ where the expectation is taken with respect to the random variable $N$.  To this end, we note that if $$N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda),$$ then
$$\operatorname{E}[z^N] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \Pr[N = n] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}.$$
I leave the remainder of this calculation as an exercise.

Then, all that remains is to let $z = M_X(t)$ after evaluating the above sum.  The result furnishes the desired MGF of $Y$.

The rest of the question should be straightforward once you have calculated the MGF of $Y$, since for each positive integer $k$,

$$\mathbb{E}[Y^k] = \frac{d^k}{dt^k}\left[M_Y(t)\right]_{t=0};$$
that is to say, the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moment of $Y$ equals the $k^{\rm th}$ derivative of the MGF of $Y$ evaluated at $0$.  The choice $k = 1$ yields $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and the variance is calculated using the second moment minus the square of the first moment; i.e., $\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[Y]^2$.

As for the "simpler and more direct" method described in part 3, how would you do this?  My suggestion is to use the linearity of expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_1 + \cdots + X_N \mid N]] = \ldots,$$

and the law of total variance:

$$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{Var}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid N]] + \mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}[Y \mid N]].$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{aligned}
M_Y(t)-1& = \mathbb{E}(e^{tY})-1\\
& = \sum_{j>1}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E} \left( e^{t \sum_{n=1}^N X_n} \vert N = j \right)\right]P(Y=j)\\
&  = \sum_{j\ge 1 }\left[\mathbb{E}\left( e^{t \sum_{n=1}^j X_n} \right)\right]e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{j}} {j!}\\
& = e^{\lambda (M_X(t)-1)}-1\end{aligned}$$

I will let you differentiate this to get the answer for 2).

For 3) condition on $N$ and use the fact that the mean of  a sum is the sum of the means and variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances.

Comment: The sum cannot exclude the case $j = 0$ because there is a positive probability that $N = 0$.  Another way to see the error is to note that a well-defined MGF must be $1$ at $t = 0$, since $M_Y(0) = \mathbb{E}[e^{0 \cdot Y}] = \mathbb{E}[e^0] = 1$.  Your MGF does not:  $$e^{\lambda(M_X(0)-1)} - 1 = 0 \ne 1.$$

Comment: @heropup I wanted to start with $M_Y(t)-1$. I have corrected the answer. Thanks for your comment.